# Javascript is returning empty value

Tags: javascript

This may seem as a dumb question, but I just can't figure out, what am I doing wrong?

I have a HTML textarea which always contains one simple sentence. What am I trying to achieve is to load this sentence into JS variable with the help of ".value;"

But when I try to print out the variable, it's always empty - [Screenshot from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKOhA.png)

Can you please tell me, what am I doing wrong, or at least point me the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please **always include code** as [formatted text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) (or if it is JS + HTML, as a working [Code Snippet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193323/344751)). Never make us re-type your code from an image before we can attempt to run your code.

Comment: Thank you for telling me. Than I'm sorry for not including the code - I'll keep that in mind in the future questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textareas have a different behavior that inputs. Their value is stored *inside* the opening and the closing tags.

Here is an example :

```js
alert(document.getElementById('textarea').value);
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">I am the value !</textarea>
```

Also next time, please include your code and the result as text, not as an image.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this is just what I needed! Also I'm sorry for not including the code - this was my first question here and I didn't realize it - I'll keep that in mind in the future questions!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
alert(document.getElementById('separator').value)
```

```html
<textarea id="separator">Lorem ipsum</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` for a `textarea` is the value enclosed between the tags `<textarea></textarea`. In your case that is `''`. Hence, you get an empty string.

You 'd be better off if you included some text between the tags. I am sure you will get the result you need then.